# Excel 2 validation Data in a cell

Tags: excel, validation

I need to add Data Validation to a cell but it has 2 conditions:
 - It should allow options from a List or a data in a Date Time Format.
I have already implemented the first condition... but I don't know how to add the second.

Can you please help me. Thank u in advance

Answer (score 2):

Let's say `B1` contains the value that you want to validate. Then the following formula formula will return `true` when `B1` is either in the list `DueDate`, or when `B1` is a valid date.

`=OR(COUNTIF(DueDate,B1)=1,NOT(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(TEXT(B1,"mm/dd/yyyy")))))`

**Explanation:**

`COUNTIF` return the number of occurrence of your input in the provided list. If it is 1, that means `B1` exists in `DueDate`.

`TEXT(B1,"dd/mm/yyyy")` first converts `B1` into the form of a date. Then `DATEVALUE` will return a number representing the date if the date is valid, otherwise it will return `#VALUE!` error.

**Conclusion:**

Apply the above formula to the cell that you want to validate, replacing `B1` with the address of your corresponding cell. A drawback of this solution is that any number that can represent a date can pass the validation as well, e.g. `123`. Nevertheless `123` is actually really a correct date in the world of Excel (it represents `05/02/1900`), so we can do nothing about this.

Comment: Thank you but how can I combine both?
In Data Validation -> Allow List ; Source= DueDate (It's a range with strings: Cancelled, Postponed, Ongoing) But the user can also enter Date time format. Thank u!

Comment: Actually after some testing on my own I found that `cell()` is not really a good choice as a formula since this function will be evaluated again only on forced re-calculation (by pressing F9). I would suggest you to write a formula yourself. I have updated my answer accordingly.